# Instruments can't catch memory leak caused by loop reference in Swift

Tags: memory, swift

```
class Client
{
    var name:String
    var account:Account!

    init(name:String)
    {
        self.name = name
        self.account = Account(client: self)
    }

    deinit
    {
        println("Client::deinit")
    }
}

class Account
{
    var client:Client
    var balance:Int

    init(client:Client)
    {
        self.client = client
        self.balance = 0
    }

    deinit
    {
        println("Account::deinit")
    }
}

var client:Client! = Client(name: "larryhou")
client = nil
```

The code above produces a loop reference situation, and I can find out client and account keep one reference count in instruments, but instruments just can't catch the leak. Would anybody tell me why?

Comment: I can see the leak in instruments just fine if I profile your code; it shows that both `Client` and `Account` are leaked objects. What do you mean by "instruments just can't catch the leak"?

Comment: I thought instruments should show up a red bar indicating memory leak in Leaks timeline, but it didn't.

Comment: I see the red bar indicating a leak when I try it. I'm using Xcode / Instruments 6.1.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using Xcode 6.0, I'll try again after I upgrade Xcode to GM6.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

I'v figured out what the problem really is after several tries, instruments can't catch memory leak and display it in a Leaks instrument with real device, but it can do with device simulator! It's so weird...

Comment: it's same to me,very wired